# Writing a matrix as a sum of two invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $n\geq 2$. Is it true that any $n\times n$ matrix with entries from a given ring (with identity) can be written as a sum of two invertible matrices with entries from the same ring ?

Comment: What's a giver ring?   giver $\to$ *given* ?

Comment: You might want to consider the answer in the $n=1$ case as an example of how you could handle the general case.  I've voted to close.

Comment: Use upper triangular matrices with non zero diagonals

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko: What if the ring is not a division ring? Additionally, over a field with two elements, the identity matrix can only be written as a sum of two invertible matrices as follows: $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I agree that my proposal does not work for all rings.

Comment: It is true for many rings.  The terminology is somethig like "clean".There is also some USENET news posts on Sums of Invertible Matrices.  A web search may help further.

Comment: There's a paper "Matrices as Sums of Invertible Matrices" 
(N.J.Lord, Math Magazine 60 #1 (1987), 33-35
= http://www.jstor.org/stable/269013 )
that does it for a field.  But commutative rings seem harder.
Try $n=2$:
Let $k$ be the two-element field, and $A = k[a,b,c,d]$.
Are there $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta \in A$ such that
$\alpha\delta - \beta\gamma = (\alpha+A)(\delta+D) - (B+\beta)(C+\gamma) = 1$ ?

Comment: Your double use of A is unfortunate.  Could you rewrite your last equation, or remind us how you overload A?

Comment: Sorry, good catch: 
$A,B,C,D$ in the last line should be $a,b,c,d$.  So what I should ask is:
$({a\phantom.b\atop c\phantom.d})$ is the sum of two invertible matrices
over $A$, one of which is $({\alpha\phantom.\beta\atop \gamma\phantom.\delta})$,
**iff**
$\alpha\delta - \beta\gamma = (\alpha+a)(\delta+d) - (b+\beta)(c+\gamma) = 1$.
Can these two simultaneous equation be solved in $A$?

Comment: The argument I remember also hinged on the 2 by 2 case, and then inducted on the order n of the matrix, but requiring the ring to have every element either be a unit or the sum of two units.  I'm not sure that it can be done otherwise.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, your [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141382/writing-a-matrix-as-a-sum-of-two-invertible-matrices#comment364893_141382) goes to [Solmsen - The world of the dead in Book 6 of the Æneid](https://www.jstor.org/stable/269013), which, while undoubtedly fascinating, probably isn't as relevant as [Lord - Matrices as sums of invertible matrices](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690135) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1572639)).  :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**The answer is negative.**

There is a nice theorem of **M. Henriksen** which says that **If $n\geq 2$ then every element of $M_n(R)$ is a sum of three units**  also he proves that there are non-unit matrices in $\bf{M_2(\Bbb{Z}_2[x_1,x_2])}$ that can not be written as a sum of two units. You can find a copy of the article [HERE](http://www.math.hmc.edu/~henriksen/publications/1974_Henriksen_Two_classes_of_rings_generated_by_their_units.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

This may help. Any $2\times 2$ matrix is a sum of four units:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & t \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} +  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & t \end{pmatrix} +  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ z & -1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -1 & y \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: If e.g. z and y are each the sum of two units, you can reduce this to two summands.

Comment: +1 For the nice identity.